# How to import PDF content with sub/superscripts?

Tags: import, pdf-format

Is there any way to import text containing superscripts in PDFs correctly to plaintext? For example,

```
Import["~/Downloads/example.pdf", "Plaintext"]
```

[image]

The imported text should be "\$35" not "\$351", it is confused by the superscript:

[image]

Here's the example pdf file with superscripts to try:

```
CloudImport @ "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/17686b9d-e609-462d-8184-03201c2d551a"
```

Comment: This superscript is just text smaller text that has been raised. It is not using a special character like: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00B9

So you would need to import it somehow including the font-size to detect whether or not it is a superscript.

Comment: How to filter based on glyph size first, seems like it should be a built-in sort of thing no?

Comment: PDF is a really bad format for exchanging computer-readable information. I appreciate you may not have an alternative, but this is likely going to be very hard.